# Large organizations connecting to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection

I work for a rather large organization and we recently started working on a cloud transition. We are not currently looking into the direct connect as an option, but would like to establish connectivity to our ec2 machines.

Of course as an org, we block port 22 and RDP, so our current model is a vpc, which we connect to via a VPN, but this model is not scalable, nor is it that convenient (RDP over VPN).

I have gone over several options on this site as well as the AWS documentation, but I can't find a reasonably scalable option. I need to be able to allow multiple users to access the resources at once, and still have a secure connections. Thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You say "VPN," but I assume you are not talking about [AWS Hardware VPN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html) which is perfectly scalable, and arguably the de facto standard for connections without Direct Connect.

Comment: send someone on a AWS Sysops course

Comment: Thank you for your answers, they were incredibly helpful!